# Use an object in switch case - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement, case

how can I load an object in switch case?

for example, this is my object

```
{"1":"Restaurant","2":"Hotel","3":"Beauty shop","4":"Physiotherapist","5":"Dentist","6":"Bar","7":"Coffee shop"}
```

**due to multilanguage, I can't write a case for each Business Type, I want to inverse that ID with the BusinessType because is a CSV importer and the client send "Restaurant", if the client send "Restaurant" I have to convert that for "1"**

how can I make it become a switch case?

I am looking for it to be inverse

for example

```
Restaurant = 1
```

not

```
1 = Restaurant
```

this is an example with one case, the object can be different according to the language

```
  switch (csvItem["Business Type"]){
    case 'Restaurant': csvItem["Business Type"] = 1;
    break;
```

**For nina solution, I have this problem**

```
let businessTypes = document.getElementById('all-business-types').value;

const
  data = businessTypes,
  switched = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [v, +k]));

console.log('switched ' + switched);
```

but in my console the result is `switched [object Object]` and if I use `console.log('switched ' + JSON.stringify(switched));` I get this result

```
{"1":2,"2":19,"3":31,"4":49,"5":71,"6":85,"7":95,"{":0,"\"":110,":":97,"R":6,"e":104,"s":106,"t":81,"a":90,"u":38,"r":91,"n":77,",":93,"H":23,"o":108,"l":27,"B":89,"y":55," ":105,"h":107,"p":109,"P":53,"i":79,"D":75,"C":99,"f":102,"}":111}
```

businessTypes in my browser log

```
{"1":"Restaurant","2":"Hotel","3":"Beauty shop","4":"Physiotherapist","5":"Dentist","6":"Bar","7":"Coffee shop"}
```

thanks for reading :)

Comment: Just for the record, that's not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch the entries and convert the key/string to a number.

```js
const
    json = '{"1":"Restaurant","2":"Hotel","3":"Beauty shop","4":"Physiotherapist","5":"Dentist","6":"Bar","7":"Coffee shop"}',
    data = JSON.parse(json),
    switched = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => [v, +k])
    );

console.log(switched);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Usage:

```
csvItem["Business Type"] = switched[csvItem["Business Type"]];
```

Comment: excuse me, it works, but when I load that "data" from an input ID, in my console has "[object Object]". If I use JSON.stringify(switched) I get this {"1":2,"2":19,"3":31,"4":49,"5":71,"6":85,"7":95,"{":0,"\"":110,":":97,"R":6,"e":104,"s":106,"t":81,"a":90,"u":38,"r":91,"n":77,",":93,"H":23,"o":108,"l":27,"B":89,"y":55," ":105,"h":107,"p":109,"P":53,"i":79,"D":75,"C":99,"f":102,"}":111}

Comment: it looks like, you are spreading some words. can you show the original object?

Comment: I updated my question with full code for this part.

Comment: it looks like, you got a JSON string and before switching, you need to parse the string to get an object. please see edit.

Comment: thanks, it works, now I'm trying to use this in a switch case

Comment: How can I set this? case 'Restaurant': csvItem["Business Type"] = 1; using this switched?

Comment: please see *usage*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want to invert the keys and values.

```js
const original = {
  "1": "Restaurant",
  "2": "Hotel",
  "3": "Beauty shop",
  "4": "Physiotherapist",
  "5": "Dentist",
  "6": "Bar",
  "7": "Coffee shop"
};


const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(original).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]));

console.log(result)
```